# SASS comma not expanding

Tags: sass

I have this SASS snippet to compile with `node-sass`:

```
.form-control-dark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);

  &::placeholder, 
  &:-ms-input-placeholder, 
  &::-ms-input-placeholder
  {
    color: darken(white, 15%);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &:focus {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  }
}
```

I expected the three "comma-ed" elements to be compiled as:

```
.form-control-dark {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.15);
  border-color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.15)
}
.form-control-dark::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  color:#d9d9d9;opacity:1 }
.form-control-dark::placeholder {
  color:#d9d9d9;opacity:1 }
.form-control-dark:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:#d9d9d9;opacity:1 }
.form-control-dark::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:#d9d9d9;opacity:1 }
```

But, instead, I get:

```
.form-control-dark {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.15);
  border-color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.15) }
.form-control-dark:-ms-input-placeholder,.form-control-dark::-ms-input-placeholder { 
  color:#d9d9d9;opacity:1 }
.form-control-dark:-ms-input-placeholder,.form-control-dark::-ms-input-placeholder,.form-control-dark::placeholder {
  color:#d9d9d9;opacity:1 }
```

Can anyone tell me what am I getting wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your output is the result of `autoprefixer` not Sass.
Try leave out the vendor versions of `&::placeholder` autoprefixer will handle the rest:

**SCSS**

```
.form-control-dark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);

  // standard only 
  &::placeholder {
    color: darken(white, 15%);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &:focus {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  }
}
```

**Compiled + autoprefixed CSS**

```
.form-control-dark {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
.form-control-dark::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control-dark:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control-dark::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control-dark::placeholder {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control-dark:focus {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: Indeed I can actually see that autoprefixer is configured as a plugin in my postcss.config.js (using a Vue CLI 3 template). My compiled output is slightly different but it works. Thanks!